# Client-side Javascript can appear where within an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Client-side `Javascript` can appear where within an `HTML` document?

A. Between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags

B. Between the `<body>`and `</body>` tags

C. Both of the above

D. None of the above

Comment: this looks like a question on an exam.

Comment: It's actually a question from a homework assignment, can you help with this? It appears the answer is C "Both of the above"

Comment: JS code can actually be placed anywhere within the <html> and </html> tag.

Comment: also, `javascript` and `java` are two diferrent things

Comment: the answers here are very interesting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Answer (score 1):

Here are codes that are placed in the different parts of the HTML. Ever variation will run no matter where the script tag is placed.

1.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello world");
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

2.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello world");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

3.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>

</head>
<body>

</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hello world");
    </script>
</html>
```

If you try out all these 3 variations where the script tags are placed in different parts of the HTML, you'll see that the `alert()` call will still run; regardless of their position in the HTML document.

So I think the answer to your question is:

> C. Both of the above

Since there is no choice that says "Anywhere within the html document"

Comment: I was thinking the same exact thing. I chose "C" as the answer. I saw that the "Script" could be place anywhere between the <body> and </body> as well as the <head> and </head> therefore, due to the wording of the question, I was thinking the best logical choice was "C"

Answer (score 0):

***It is a good idea to place scripts at the bottom of the  element.
This can improve page load, because HTML display is not blocked by scripts loading.***

[You should prefer here:](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

Comment: are you saying that the answer is "None of the above"

Comment: You mean between what?

Comment: According to your reference it appears that the answer should be B: "Both of the above"

Answer (score 0):

I chose "C" both of the above because the "Script" can be placed anywhere between the  and < / body> as well as the < head> and < / head> It appears the most logical answer to go with in this situation is "C"